# Determining my Kia Forte Trim Level

Tags: engine, trim, vin

I'm trying to figure out my trim level on my kia forte from 2011. The sticker on the inside of the drivers door jamb says "trim: WK". What trim level is this and what engine do I have? Is there anyway to figure these things out from my VIN?

Answer (score 1):

The information you've provided isn't enough to know unfortunately. The "WK" is the colour of the interior trim of your car (in this case black). Example for the 2011 Forte here:

https://www.vehiclehistory.com/report/kia/forte/2011/features/colors

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different free VIN decoders online. I don't have a Kia but AutoZone's decoder tells me the trim of my Fiat Abarth: https://www.autozone.com/vin-decoder

The DMV's decoder doesn't tell me my Fiat is an Abarth trim but it listed a bunch of its standard equipment based on my VIN: https://www.dmv.org/vehicle-history/vin-decoder.php

Answer (score 0):

This site worked for my subaru. [link](https://www.faxvin.com/vin-decoder)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.